# Process privilege to open the roots of network drives

Tags: python, security, winapi

Which process privilege is required to open the root of network drives?

Here, `Z:\\` is the network drive.

```
import win32file
import win32con

win32file.CreateFile(
    'Z:\\', win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32con.ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY,
    win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32file.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | win32file.FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, None
)
```

The above raises the exception `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`.

I've acquired all of the process privileges on msdn now, but the above still doesn't work. Is it possible to open the root of network drives in userspace?

Following Harry's comments, I checked whether I have the appropriate privileges:

```
with closing(win32security.OpenProcessToken(
    win32process.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
)) as token:
    print(win32security.GetTokenInformation(token, win32security.TokenPrivileges))
```

This returns:

```
((4, 2), (5, 2), (8, 2), (9, 2), (10, 2), (11, 2), (12, 2), (13, 2), (14, 2), (15, 2), (17, 2), (18, 2), (19, 2), (20, 2), (22, 2), (23, 3), (24, 2), (25, 2), (28, 2), (29, 3), (30, 3), (33, 2), (34, 2), (35, 2))
```

`SE_SECURITY_NAME` has an `LUID` of 8, so I think I do have the required privilege.

Comment: According to the documentation, you need SE_SECURITY_NAME to get ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY access.  Double-check that you are actually being given the privileges that you've requested; it is not an error to request a privilege that you're not entitled to, such a request is silently ignored.  (It may also be simply impossible to get ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY on the root of a network drive; what are you actually trying to do?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've checked whether I have the appropriate privileges like you suggested, I think I do, see my updated question. But you're right on `win32con.ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`, without this flag the call to `CreateFile` works.

Comment: If you don't need ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, then you don't need to enable any privileges.  (The FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag doesn't require privilege, so long as the ACL on the target directory grants you access.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm trying to call `BackupRead` on the root of the drive to get the SACLs, now that you say this I'm wondering whether they have SACLs?

Comment: Apparently I can't open files on the network drive with `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` either. Probably a remote issue then.

Comment: I'd double-check that you have SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege on the remote computer as well as the local one.  But I wouldn't be too surprised if it turns out that SMB didn't support SACLs.